# Duplicate Symbol error from clang/llvm compiler

Tags: c++

While working tonight on a project, I struggled for a while with a linker error that complained about a "duplicate symbol".

I eventually figured out that I had a helper function defined instead of just declared in my header file and this was the source of the problem (lost over an hour chasing this).

why can I define inline functions in my header like this;

```
int get_val const {return r;}
```

but the same definition outside the class throws a linker error?

Comment: Haven't we all spent innumerable hours chasing ghosts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-class member function definitions are implicitly marked `inline`, whereas non-member ones are not, so, if your definition is in a header file, you break the [***one-definition-rule***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (ODR) as soon as more than one translation unit includes your header. `inline` provides a means to get around this.

So you need to explicitly mark your non-member function as `inline`:

```
inline int foo() {return 42;}
```

Alternatively, only declare it in the header and define it in a `.cpp` file.

See [this related post on `inline` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971736/c-inline-function).

Answer (score 0):

If you needed a inline function, you should define it in a header file. You can see C++ Primer(4th edtion)， which has some pages about inline function. I think you can get your answer there.